# How do I access the data from one column and make changes against another column in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, multiple-columns, kaggle, data-preprocessing

So I am trying to preprocess the 911.csv dataset from Kaggle ([911 Calls](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mchirico/montcoalert)) and I found that there are missing values in the Zip code (zip) column. I preprocessed the dataset a bit and found out what Township (twp) has missing zip values: 6 towns, to be specific.

The idea is to take the column Township, and corresponding to the towns that has 'nan' value, I would like to assign their respective zip code in the zip column.

It sounds simple but I've been banging my head against the wall over this a couple of hours now.

Please help.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can groupby twp column and fillna in zip with value.

```
df["zip"] = df["zip"].fillna(df.groupby("twp")["zip"].transform("first"))
```